# Bootstrap 5 Dropdown & Navs: Cannot read property 'children' of null

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown, bootstrap-5

I get this Dev Console error message "Cannot read property 'children of null" while I'm trying to use a dropdown button with Nav Tabs in Navbar Component.

when I click on the dropdown item to display nav-link in navbar I get this Dev Console error message "Cannot read property 'children of null"

**Live Example:** https://codepen.io/themes4all/pen/bGWjMzZ

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light py-3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="nav-tab" class="dropdown" role="tablist">
                    <button type="button" id="dropdownEx" class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Select Item</button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownEx">
                        <li>
                            <button type="button" role="tab" id="nav-example-1-tab" class="dropdown-item active" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-example-1" aria-controls="nav-example-1" aria-selected="true">
                                Example 01
                            </button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button type="button" role="tab" id="nav-example-2-tab" class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-example-2" aria-controls="nav-example-2" aria-selected="false">
                                Example 02
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" id="nav-example-1" class="tab-pane fade show active" aria-labelledby="nav-example-1-tab">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Example 01</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"></ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" id="nav-example-2" class="tab-pane fade" aria-labelledby="nav-example-2-tab">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Example 02</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tabs (data-bs-toggle="tab") should be contained inside a `nav nav-tabs`...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light py-3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="nav-tab" class="dropdown" role="tablist">
                    <button type="button" id="dropdownEx" class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Select Item</button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-tabs" aria-labelledby="dropdownEx">
                        <li class="dropdown-item p-0">
                            <button type="button" role="tab" id="nav-example-1-tab" class="dropdown-item active" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-example-1" aria-controls="nav-example-1" aria-selected="true"> Example 01 </button>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item p-0">
                            <button type="button" role="tab" id="nav-example-2-tab" class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-example-2" aria-controls="nav-example-2" aria-selected="false"> Example 02 </button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" id="nav-example-1" class="tab-pane fade show active" aria-labelledby="nav-example-1-tab">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Example 01</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown"></ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" id="nav-example-2" class="tab-pane fade" aria-labelledby="nav-example-2-tab">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a href="#" role="button" id="navbarDropdown2" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Example 02</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2"></ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/4vWPAEwNpE)

**Caveat:** This is not the intended use of Bootstrap Tabs and Dropdowns. Dropdowns aren't designed used to toggle Tabs, and Tabs aren't meant to be used in the Navbar.

Comment: the dropdown not closing it should still toggling

Comment: The whole thing is not intended use of Tabs. As a workaround/hack you can use `dropdown-menu collapse`

Comment: I'm not looking for collapse I'm trying to display the navbar items based on dropdown button active item

Comment: Again, you're not using Bootstrap as it was intended - another XY problem?. Using the collapse class is a workaround. See the demo.

Comment: any idea to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

**This doesn't describe why it's happening, but if you would like a solution.**

Remove some of the attributes associated with the dropdown list item buttons (see below for example). Depending on what you want to do, you can either set up JavaScript event listeners for those buttons. Or you can change the buttons to anchor tags and navigate to a different page.

```
<div id="nav-tab" class="dropdown" role="tablist">
    <button type="button" id="dropdownEx" class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Select Item</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownEx">
        <li>
            <button type="button" role="tab" id="nav-example-1-tab" class="dropdown-item active">
                Example 01
            </button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" role="tab" id="nav-example-2-tab" class="dropdown-item">
                Example 02
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Leaf" menu items like *Example 1* and *Example 2* should not contain `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"`